# Which version of node am I using?

Tags: node.js

I recently updated my version of node using homebrew to begin learning angular and ran into something curious. Upon using:

```
brew upgrade node
```

It responds:

```
node 13.7.0 already installed
```

But then when I check which version, this happens.

```
node -v
v10.15.3
```

So am I really using 13.7? Because according to https://angular.io/guide/setup-local I need version 10.9 or better. So 10.15 would certainly be a problem.

Comment: Why would 10.15 be a problem? 15 > 9

Comment: no, you are using v10.15.3, try to close the terminal and open it again and check which version you have again, but anyway you are fine to use `v10.15.3` for Angular

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick response, both of you. I did in fact close the terminal and reopen and it was still 10.15. But if that version works for me to at least get started then that's great. And like I said, the link above says that I need at least version 10.9

Comment: I suggest using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to manage node versions. It works more reliably than any other method I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command `which -a node` in your command shell.

That will list all the `node` binaries in your `PATH`. More than likely your path is mucked up and the MacOS installed version of `node` is found in the path before the `brew`-installed version of `node.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it highlighted why this issue even popped up in the first place. Thanks for the tip!